# What is the difference between pyodbc vs sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql

Both are supposed to parse connection string and able to insert into say, SQL Server from pandas dataframe.
What is the real difference here?

Answer (score 8):

PyODBC allows you connecting to and using an ODBC database using the standard [DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). SQL Alchemy is a toolkit that resides one level higher than that and provides a [variety of features](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html):

- Object-relational mapping (ORM)
- Query constructions
- Caching
- Eager loading

and others. It can work with PyODBC or any other driver that supports DB API 2.0.